# Create users in LDAP using Django

Tags: django, authentication, ldap, backend, django-auth-ldap

I am having trouble with the LDAP authentification module [django-auth-ldap](http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/index.html). I am using the example configuration from this site: http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/

I'd like to do two things:

1) Authentificate against LDAP:
For the moment, my LDAP database is empty, I didn't add anything to it, in fact I don't know how to. However, I still am able to log in into my django-based site with my old logins/passwords stored in my django database. Why is that? Shouldn't this be ignored, shouldn't the login process occur with LDAP user/passwords instead? In other words, if my LDAP database is empty, shouldn't every single of my login fail? However, it doesn't, I have the impression that django completly ignores the django-auth-ldap module.

2) Synchronize LDAP with django (and not the other way around)
I don't want to use an existing user database to authentificate against. I want to be able to create new users in Django and propagate these users to LDAP so they can be shared by other services, in my case, an openfire server. How do you do that with django-auth-ldap?

Here is the copy/paste of my configuration:

```
# Baseline configuration.
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "127.0.0.1"

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=admin,dc=nodomain"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "admin"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=users,dc=nodomain",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")

# Set up the basic group parameters.
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=django,ou=groups,dc=nodomain",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr="cn")

# Only users in this group can log in.
AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = "cn=enabled,ou=django,ou=groups,dc=nodomain"

# Populate the Django user from the LDAP directory.
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}

AUTH_LDAP_PROFILE_ATTR_MAP = {
    "employee_number": "employeeNumber"
}

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "cn=active,ou=django,ou=groups,dc=nodomain",
    "is_staff": "cn=staff,ou=django,ou=groups,dc=nodomain",
    "is_superuser": "cn=superuser,ou=django,ou=groups,dc=nodomain"
}

AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True

AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True

AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600


# Keep ModelBackend around for per-user permissions and maybe a local
# superuser.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Sorry I don't know much about LDAP, I just installed it this morning so my question may sound naive. I just need a centralized user base that I would be able to update and share between several servers.

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 9):

1) Your configuration has two authentication backends installed:

`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', )`

Django will attempt to authenticate against each one in turn until it finds one that succeeds (or until it runs out). Since your LDAP directory is empty, it will presumably always fail, so ModelBackend will always get a shot. If you don't want to authenticate users against the Django user database, you have to remove ModelBackend from the list.

2) django-auth-ldap doesn't propagate Django users up to LDAP, only the other way around. It's designed to allow Django deployments to authenticate against existing LDAP services that are managed separately. To manipulate the contents of an LDAP directory from a Django app you might want to look at [django-ldapdb](http://opensource.bolloretelecom.eu/projects/django-ldapdb/).